# Compiling PHP on Windows with /MT

Tags: php, c++

I need to link PHP statically to a project on which I am working. In order to do this, I believe that I need to compile PHP with /MT, but it appears that it is being done in /MD.

The only real documentation I have been able to find on compiling PHP is at https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild and this does not cover my requirement.

Can this be done, or am I incorrect in my assumptions?

Comment: Do you mean you have a PHP script that you'd like included in your C++ program?

Comment: No, I'm trying to statically link the whole PHP engine to a C++ program. However I'm pretty sure I should be writing a SAPI at this point. Or just using FastCGI

Comment: /MT and /MD specify how your application use runtime libraries. /MT: application use the static ones, /MD: application use dynamic DLL. This is not an issue for you problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why exactly you want to do this, but you can come pretty close by building PHP as a static binary and using that binary later from your C++ application. This should be portable and should meet your requirements without actually linking it to your application.

To do this, you need to include `--enable-static` when configuring. For example:

```
./configure --enable-static=yes \
    --enable-fastcgi \
    --enable-force-cgi-redirect \
    --enable-discard-path \
    --prefix=/server/php \
    --exec-prefix=/server/php \
    --with-config-file-path=/server/php \
    --disable-all \
    --enable-shared=no \
    --enable-session \
    --with-gd \
    --with-zlib-dir \
    --with-freetype-dir \
    --enable-sockets
    --with-freetype-dir=/usr/local
```

You should also add the `-all-static` flag to the `BUILD_CGI` in your `Makefile`.
After that run `make` and you should get a static PHP binary.
You can now use it from your C++ project without any external requirements for it.

On the other hand, if you can meet your requirements by creating a C++ PHP extension,
you should take a look at [PHP-CPP](http://www.php-cpp.com/):

> The PHP-CPP library is a C++ library for developing PHP extensions. It
>   offers a collection of well documented and easy-to-use classes that
>   can be used and extended to build native extensions for PHP.